# Список с иконками и текстом. Android

Tags: java, android, design

Как лучше реализовать список с иконками слева и текстом правей от них? При этом важна возможность локализации приложения, т.е использования string ресурсов.

Comment: что конкретно вас интересует? Что вы хотите получить в ответ? Готовый код?

Comment: listView с кастомным layout'ом?

Comment: Хотелось бы получить возможные пути решения, ссылку на что-то , что может помочь или объяснение.

Comment: Вам нужен кастомный адаптер. Понятие более чем очень широко распространенное. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20listview%20custom%20adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно будет кастомизировать `ListView`. Попробуйте поискать типо "Custom `ListView Adapter`" или "Custom `ListView`". Вот пара ссылок, может такое имелли ввиду, [Первая](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1), [Вторая](http://www.android-examples.com/android-custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-using-arrayadapter-string/).

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать CardView. Вот пример разметки для одного элемента списка, с текстом и картинкой.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/Wide"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Wrap"
            android:id="@+id/nameFolder"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[Ссылка на статью](http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/)